# My JFrame wont show my container and there is No errors

Tags: java, jframe, containers

I dont know what is wrong it worked before and i just changed it by adding if's and reading files the code is a universal jframe where it reads a file and to set what buttons appear it reads files but it doesnt work anymore. i have tested to see if it was reading the file correctly which it was so it isnt the data. Here is my code  below. Im sorry if it isn't indented properly Thank You

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
 Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

 /**
 *
 * @author cyoung
 */
public class Frametemplate {
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;
    final static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
    final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;
    String text1 = "";

    boolean Button1 = false;

String Redirect1 = "";
String Redirect2 = "";
String Class ="";
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

                new Frametemplate().Start1();

             }
    });
    // TODO code application logic here
}
public  void add(Container pane){
    try {
            FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("JFrame.sav");
            ObjectInputStream save = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);


            text1 = (String) save.readObject();

            text7 = (String) save.readObject();
            Class = (String) save.readObject();


            save.close();
        } catch (Exception exc) {

            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
            FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("JFrame1.sav");
            ObjectInputStream save = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);
            Button1 = (boolean) save.readObject();



            save.close();
        } catch (Exception exc) {

            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Button5+Class+text5+Redirect1);


    if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
        pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    }
    URL resource = getClass().getResource("Graphitebackground.v2.jpg");


    ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon(resource);
    URL resource3 = getClass().getResource("Graphitebackground.v4.jpg");


    ImageIcon i3 = new ImageIcon(resource3);
    URL resource1 = getClass().getResource("Graphitebackground.v3.jpg");
    ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(resource1);  
    JLabel background = new JLabel(i2);
    background.setSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
    background.setVisible(true);
    background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    JButton button;
pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
if (shouldFill) {
//natural height, maximum width
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
}

    if (Button1 == true){
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
        if (shouldWeightX) {
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        }
        label2.setText(text1);
        label2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,-50));

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = -1;
        label2.setForeground(Color.RED);
        label2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,50));
        background.add(label2, c);
    }




   //third row
        background.add(l1, c);
        pane.add(background);
    }
}



public  void Start1(){











   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tank Game Online");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    //Set up the content pane.
    add(frame.getContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: Please shorten your code to the bare minimum to reproduce the issue. It will be easier for us to find what's wrong, and maybe you even find the problem while doing it already.

Comment: i cant shorten it as i dont know what the issue is so i am sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn’t working because I add all the buttons to the background and the background gets added to the pane which the jframe opens but But the add the background to the pane is in a if statement where if Maintext = true that is why it is showing nothing.